Indulging your vice when you've got no dice
During downtime, if you choose to indulge your vice to recover stress, you roll a number of dice equal to your lowest attribute rating. What do you do if your lowest attribute rating is zero? My on-the-spot ruling was to roll two dice and take the lower, as is common for some other actions, but what's the real solution?

I just want to appreciate the rhyme in the title.

Core system recite, your ruling was right
When you indulge your vice, the rules ask you to "make an attribute roll":

Make an attribute roll using your character’s lowest attribute rating

Unfortunately, there is no "attribute roll" in the core system. Instead, we have four types of rolls: Action roll, Downtime roll, Fortune roll, and Resistance roll.
The enigmatic attribute roll looks like a Resistance roll:

You make the roll using one of your character’s attributes (Insight, Prowess, or Resolve)

But this doesn't really matter, since the rules are the same for any type of roll:

If you ever need to roll but you have zero (or negative) dice, roll two dice and take the single lowest result.

So yes, you just roll two dice and take the lower.
